# How to migrate tables with foreign keys in Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to use Pentaho Keetle to do some data migration. I would like to create a transformation to accomplish the following:

I have the following tables in the source:

**table 1**

id [PK]

name

**table 2**

id [PK]

source_id [FK with table 1.id]

state

I have the same structures in the destination server. Let's say i would like to migrate 10 rows from **table 1** along with their relations from **table 2** in the destination server.

How would i do that with a Keetle transformation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would do it in 2 transformations, with a job wrapped around them. Do table1 first, then table2.

Answer (score 1):

How to migrate tables with foreign keys in Pentaho Kettle?

Create 3 tables “USER”, “USER_STATE”, “USER_MIGRATE”

### USER

Create 2 fields “ID” and “NAME” in USER table as displayed in the screen shot

[image]

### USER_STATE

Create 3 fields “ID”, “USER_ID”, “STATE” in the USER_STATE table as displayed in the screen shot. Here USER_ID is the foreign key of the “USER” table.

[image]

### USER_MIGRATE

This is the table where we will migrate the data from the other two tables “USER” and “USER_STATE”. Create 5 fields “ID”, “USER_ID”, “USER_STATE_ID”, “USER_NAME”, “USER_STATE” as displayed in the screen shot

[image]

In this table “USER_STATE_ID” is the foreign key of the table USER_STATE

We can do it in one transformation. We will use the join query to select the data from the two table “USER” and “USER_STATE”. Then we can put these data into our third table which is the migrate table

Please find the join query below

The below screen shot tells about how to map the table fields

[image]

This is the transformation used to migrate the data from the source tables to destination tables

[image]